# array of arrays in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

i have profile table wher it extends parent type and embeds many phone numbers.. here goes the code ---

```
-@profile.parent_type.each_with_index do |parent,index|
  = f.fields_for "parent_attributes[]", parent do |parent_fields|

    %tr
      %td{:class => 'table_hr'}


        = parent_fields.label :lname, "Last name"
        = parent_fields.text_field :lname

        = parent_fields.label :fname, "First name"
        = parent_fields.text_field :fname
```

can some explain what exactly this code means...

Comment: Did you write that code? What do you want to do? This is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing would be for you to familiarize yourself with the HAML language reference here:

http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html

That page will explain each of the individual elements for you so you can understand them. The other thing I'd recommend, obviously, is to run the code itself and learn to understand how it works.

But at a high-level, here's what's happening.

The line:

```
@profile.parent_type.each_with_index do |parent,index|
```

is essentially grabbing the profile and pulling all the `parent_type` records the users profile points to, and then looping through them -- passing both the `parent_type` record as well as the `index` of that record into the loop.

The the line:

```
 = f.fields_for "parent_attributes[]", parent do |parent_fields|
```

is creating *form fields* for the `parent_attributes` of each of the parent_type records. These will get posted when the form gets posted.

The other lines:

```
 %tr
  %td{:class => 'table_hr'}


    = parent_fields.label :lname, "Last name"
    = parent_fields.text_field :lname

    = parent_fields.label :fname, "First name"
    = parent_fields.text_field :fname
```

render once for each parent_type record and are the attributes for the record. There should essentially be a table listing these out with one row per record.

Is that clear?

Comment: Thanks - I'm glad this helped. If the answer was helpful, it would be appreciated if ou would consider 'accepting' it. Thanks!